# Optimizing html5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, canvas

Right now I've got two game loops in a game I'm making. A draw loop that loops through an array of objects on screen and a logic loop that does game logic. I have the logic loop running about 10 more frames than the draw loop. I have this set up like this because doing game logic may take longer and I don't want it to interfere with the draw loop.

I have the logic loop set up like this:

```
vs.logicloop = function(){
    vs.Gameloop();
    //do the updating of object scripts
    if(vs.windowActive){
        var l = vs.scenegraph.length;
        var i = 0;
        while(i < l){
            vs.scenegraph[i].logicScript();
            i++;
        }
    }
    //restart loop
    setTimeout(vs.logicloop, 1000/(vs.fps+10));
};
```

and the draw loop like this:

```
vs.drawloop = function(){
    //clear the screen
    vsd.clr();
    //goes through everything in the scene
    //graph and draws it and runs each object's
    //personal draw code
    if(vs.windowActive){
        var l = vs.scenegraph.length;
        var i = 0;
        while(i < l){
            vs.ctx.save();
            vs.scenegraph[i].update();
            vs.scenegraph[i].draw();
            vs.scenegraph[i].drawScript();
            vs.ctx.restore();
            i++;
        }
    }
    //restart loop
    setTimeout(vs.drawloop, 1000/vs.fps);
};
```

I'm using setTimeout because I heard that setInterval will cause loops to overlap if one isn't finished yet. **Are there any optimizations I can do to really get some speed? Especially optimizing the game loops.**

I've heard of some javascript engines getting thousands of objects on screen at once. I can't imagine how they do that, at most mine can get up to 100 objects on screen on a very old computer and about 700 on a reasonably stocked computer. And that's without a lot of game code running in the background and before I've worked out how to do pixel perfect collision detection and physics.

My process is to draw a background color fillRect over the canvas every draw loop, then looping through all the objects and drawing their draw code. Also it doesn't try to draw objects out of view.

This is my first paying job, and I really want to impress. Plus I can keep ownership of the engine once I'm done with the game.

Thanks A Lot

Comment: I did some searching around and I heard using multiple canvases would help, I think I'll try that too, but I'd really like to hear any input on getting the gameloop to run faster

Comment: What browsers are you supporting with this?

Answer (score 15):

- if you use floating values for sprite coordinates, try converting them to integers. that will cost you losing subpixel rendering but you will gain a lot of speed.
- don't use images with odd widths. always use widths as powers of 2.
- this one is hard to implement in some cases but if your game is suitable, don't clear screen and redraw everything each frame. instead, draw changed parts.
- if you have to clear the canvas, don't draw a blank rectangle. try setting the canvas width/height again with the same size. that should reset the pixels faster than rectangle drawing.

rest of the methods i can suggest are not HTML5 canvas dependent but general subjects like using bit shiftings, inverse loops, and operator instead of modulo when possible, precalculations etc.

Comment: This answer is outdated and partially incorrect. With all due respect, there is no necessity to use images with dimensions of a power of 2. It nets you no performance gain. Also, clearRect is faster than the canvas.width hack. (Source: http://jsperf.com/canvas-clearrect-vs-width/5)

Comment: When i wrote these advices, i've personally made some tests on IE, Chrome and FF. IE and Chrome both performed better with canvas width hack while FF gave almost equal speed on Windows platform. So, it wasn't an untested memorized advice, it was a tested one. In time, clearRect became a better solution, that's correct.

Comment: When it comes to using not power of two (NPOT) width images, i still advice not to use them. Because canvas is using hardware acceleration and many graphic card drivers don't like NPOT textures. If you try NPOT images with WebGL, you'll probably see a blank rectangle. The reason NPOT images work with canvas is browsers are handling NPOT images by doing a workaround and putting them in a power of two sized buffer which means loosing CPU time. If i'd said "NPOT images don't work in canvas" that would be wrong. It's still a good call not to use them since they are slower by graphic card's nature.

Comment: In hardware accelerated Canvas environments there's still no performance gain when you use images with POT dimensions. If you think there are, feel free to post proof. ;)
I am aware of the advantages of POT dimensions btw. I've made games in C++ and OpenGL before. They just don't apply to Canvas inside the browser currently.

Comment: When there is hw acceleration, you don't need to know about how browsers handle things if you have the basic knowledge on how graphic cards handle textures. So, if NPOT textures fail to render like sometimes happens with WebGL, you can clearly see the side effect. When it accepts any size of texture, you must understand that they created some workarounds for this which will slow down the execution even if only at the initialization stage. I'm not gonna search for a link or examine browser source codes to prove sth here (i don't have that much free time) but i can give you some links.

Comment: Read "Texture packer" section. http://blog.ludei.com/techniques-to-optimize-memory-use-in-ludeis-canvas-environment/

Comment: I did specifically mention browsers though, but I'll give you that it does apply to CocoonJS and TexturePacker did a great job reducing the memory load in our own CocoonJS game. :) I still stand by my point concerning browsers though (which CocoonJS's Canvas+ environment definitely isn't). It would be the last thing I would recommend as an optimization for someone developing an canvas project for the browser. I'll gladly check out another link if it indeed does concern browser performance tho!

Answer (score 13):

Oh geez, I could probably write you a full sonnet here if you posted all your code. Here's a quick rundown:

Read Emir's answer. All of those are good except the last one which is very dependent on the situation. Setting canvas.width = canvas.width to clear the canvas can be faster on some browsers but it also clobbers all canvas state (ie the last set fill and font) which can slow things down because setting those properties is actually painfully slow.

Read my articles on Canvas performance: http://simonsarris.com/blog/tag/performance

I have a lot of other tips saved up in a private document that I'm writing a small ebook out of. If you want early access to it I can probably allow that.

Pick up [High performance JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X) by Zakas and read it.

Don't use save() and restore() like you are in the quoted code unless you **must**. They are just slowing things down.

For the timer see http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Multiple canvases for foreground-background-middleground can definitely help. Caching things on in-memory canvases can definitely help. It all depends on what you're drawing.

A lot of performance problems are due to death by a thousand tiny cuts. For instance:

```
        vs.scenegraph[i].update();
        vs.scenegraph[i].draw();
        vs.scenegraph[i].drawScript();
```

To

```
        var scene = vs.scenegraph[i];
        scene.update();
        scene.draw();
        scene.drawScript();
```

Will help a *minute* amount. How many opportunities for minute-amount stuff you have I don't know - we'd need to see a lot more code.

Answer (score 7):

> I heard that setInterval will cause loops to overlap if one isn't finished yet.

This is false, JavaScript is single threaded. This means that if your first interval is still running when it hits the next step, the next step will be delayed until the first step has finished computing. This also means that you can't rely on setInterval to be accurate if you start doing a lot of computations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo much of all has been said by other people.  Integer values, use request animation frame, etc. If drawing text be careful how often you set fonts.  Also you might find using an object pool can help if you are creating lots of temporary objects per frame.

As a general read on game loops I'd recommend this: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/