# Positioning 200+ div's every tick, is it faster with the HTML5 <canvas> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm creating a game with jQuery, where I need to update 200+ (sometimes 300) div's every tick (about 0.02 seconds). Right now performance is great (although pushing the limits) and runs on most browsers.

My game uses "units", a class that has a Create() and Update() function.
Create() creates a 32x32 sized div and gives it a name, while Update() sets the position with two important css calls:

```
    $("#unit"+this.uid).css("left", posx+"px");
    $("#unit"+this.uid).css("top", posy+"px");
```

I've been told HTML5 would run faster "because the content of a HTML5 canvas does not change the DOM tree". Would this have an effect in my case? I'd test this myself, but I have no experience or knowledge about HTML5 and like to know if I should try anything at all first.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in http://craftyjs.com/ - a entity/component based game framework that supports html5 and DOM elements.

Comment: Possibly — I think the suggestion you’ve been given is to use the HTML5 `<canvas>` tag to draw your units, rather than using a `<div>` for each unit. I’ve not done anything like this myself, so I’ve no idea what you could expect performance-wise, but here are some demos of `<canvas>`, including some games: http://www.canvasdemos.com/

Comment: And this Stack Overflow questions discusses `<canvas>` performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681993/optimizing-html5-canvas-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to explore CSS3 transitions.  You can animate css properties over a period of time, instead of every tick.  It also is able to use hardware acceleration on webkit browsers.