# Why is drawing POT images faster than NPOT images?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I was looking into canvas speed optimizations, and I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682200/999400

> - don't use images with odd widths. always use widths as powers of 2.

So I'm wondering, why is this faster?

I have seen posts that explain that this helps with old graphics cards (when using OpenGL & such), but I'm talking about speed, not compatability, and about canvas, not OpenGL/WebGL.

Comment: I think it's because it makes mipmap building easier - if you have a power of two size, you can just half the size and take every other element to build the first mipmap, half again etc for successively smaller mipmaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html#name2

Comment: @Patashu, so if I get you correctly, it helps with the _loading_ then?

Comment: Another reason may be that factors and divisors of 2 are easier for a computer to deal with, as they can be computed with fast bitshifts, compared to the slower modulo and division. Though I'm not sure exactly where it comes into play, I suspect it is important.

Comment: @Patashu You may be correct for 3D applications, but generally it's to help with memory consumption.

Comment: @Jarrod Right, that's a good point - what I'm thinking about is more relevant for 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's faster because you can use the << operator rather than the * oprator. I.e It's faster to perform a 'shift left by 1' (multiply by two) than it is to perform a 'muliply by 43'. One can get around this limitation by adding padding bytes to the end of each row of the image (as MS did for in memory bitmaps), but essentially, it's a consequence of the speed difference between the two instructions.

In the old days of 8bit 320x200 (mode 13h), you could index a pixel with the simple formula:

`pixOffset = xPos + yPos * 320;`

But this was slooow. A much better alternative was to use

**C**

`pixOffset = xPos + (yPos * 256) + (yPos * 64)`

**Asm**

```
mov ax, xPos    ;   ax = xPos
mov bx, yPos    ;   bx = yPos
shl bx, 6       ;   bx = yPos * 64
add ax, bx      ;   ax = xPos + (yPos * 64)
shl bx, 2       ;   bx = yPos * 256
add ax, bx      ;   ax = xPos + yPos * 320
```

This may seem counter-intuitive, but when well written, it only uses single clock instructions. I.e you could calculate the offset in 6 clock cycles. Of course, pipelining and cache misses complicate the scenario.

It's also far, far cheaper to implement shift registers in hardware than a full multiplication unit, both in $$ and transistors. Consequently, the same number of transistors can be used to provide better performance, or fewer can be be used for the same performance at lower power dissipation.

AFAIK, the mul (and div) instructions of modern processors are implemented with the help of look-up tables. This has for the most part, mitigated the problem, but it isn't without it's problems either. For further reading, look into the Pentium fdiv bug (a look-up table was wrongly populated inside the chips)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug

So in closing, it's essentially an artefact of the hardware/software used to implement the functionality.

Comment: Is this answer meant for this question? This answer looks pretty ...intense :P

Comment: :grin: Yup. Unfortunately, many aspects of hardware/software design and integration are intense. (But lots of fun to investigate and understand)

Comment: Thanks, this does answer a bit of the "speed" issue, but from what I get, this is quite a small issue, isn't it?

Comment: A pleasure. Yes, it does seem to be a fairly small difference - likely one that has decreased over the 15 years since I was really conversant with x86 assembly. But it's quite complex. It is easier to optimize code to work with powers of two resolutions. It's also the way the graphics hardware (used to?) prefer. Also, consider that memory alignment will complicate it somewhat. You either have to (a) suffer a more cycles for non-aligned memory, or (b) waste memory aligning it, followed by wasting instructions to access it. This then makes it larger in memory, leading to further cache misses.

Comment: Okay, one more question, would resizing an image so that it's a POT (the unused space would be transparent) faster than using a non-POT? I assume no, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be faster, depending on how the image is used. If you 'draw' the transparent areas, it may not be. If however, you adjust your UV co-ordinates such that only the visible areas are shown, then yes, it would be faster. This is the approach taken by games and openGL/dirextX. I.e a 6x6 image would be put into an 8x8 bitmap, with the UVs set to leftTop = [0,0] and rightBot[0.75,0.75]. If it were still 6x6, the co-ords would be leftTop [0,0] and rightBot [1,1] - Also, the canvas _is_ hardware accelerated where supported, so it would seem like a prudent approach to resize to a POT.